# How to print a file selected by radio Button in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I'm not speak English very well, but i do my best. :)
I need print a CrystalReport.prt selected by a Radio Button on C# Windows Form (Visual Studio 2022).

[image]

```
-- This is the code for my current button that does the action. But this it's gonna changes.
 private void btnBuscarF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                dta_factura.Fill(DB_Pruebas1.sp_viewFactura, Convert.ToInt32(cbxIdFactura.Text));
                Factura reporte = new Factura();
                string dir = @"~\Factura.rpt";
                reporte.Load(dir);
                reporte.SetDataSource(DB_Pruebas1);
                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reporte;
                crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is your specific problem? Reports have nothing to do with `RadioButton` controls. If you want to know which `RadioButton` is checked then use `if` statements. That's true regardless of what you want to do based on the selection. If you were to write code for printing two different reports, which part(s) would change? Those are the parts you set in the `if` blocks.

Comment: you want to change the report or you want to pass parameter using radio button value?